# how can i know if google rsync is working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, rsync

I'm running gsutil rsync, and there was the result.

```
# gsutil -m rsync /mydata/ gs://mybucket/

WARNING: gsutil rsync uses hashes when modification time is not available at
both the source and destination. Your crcmod installation isn't using the
module's C extension, so checksumming will run very slowly. If this is your
first rsync since updating gsutil, this rsync can take significantly longer than
usual. For help installing the extension, please see "gsutil help crcmod".

Building synchronization state...
Starting synchronization...
```

Then i try to know if google rsync is working by "ps -aux" command but there're no gsutil or something like rsync.

after about 30 mimutes i do check google bucket but nothing change. there're nothing be uploaded.

How can i know if google rsync is running
Can anyone help me

Comment: When you ran the "ps -aux" command had the gsutil command not yet completed? From the output you showed above it looks like it might have run to completion (and if it found nothing to copy it would exit pretty quickly after the synchronization state was built).

Comment: @MikeSchwartz I answered the question below. Can u check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the problem. In my case, the folder that i wanted to synce have a couple child folder.

```
# gsutil -m rsync /my_parent_folder/ gs://mybucket/
```

here my file: /my_parent_folder/child_folder/child_folder/my_file.txt
Then i was trying to sync the last child folder and it completed successfully.

```
# gsutil -m rsync /my_parent_folder/child_folder/child_folder/ gs://mybucket/
```

I misunderstood that how "google rsync is working" too. I have thought that i run the command above once then my file can be synced automatically when my file had a change.
But it seems to be whenever i want to sync file, I must run the command above again.

But another question. How do I can sync from my parent folder. My child folder are not fixed. It depend on condition like datetime and the user name in my apps that created file.

Comment: The answer is "-r -d" options
`gsutil -m rsync -r -d /my_parent_folder/ gs://mybucket/`